# How to where like on JSON data

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a table user where in a column billing containing different JSON data.

I want to get only the user where his/her JSON data containing `"ContractEnd":"0"`
some of it containing `"ContractEnd":"1"`, `"ContractEnd":"2"` i want only `"ContractEnd":"0"`

I tried like this

```
$user = App\User->whereRaw("(billing LIKE '%"ContractEnd":"0"%')")->get();
```

but it returns an error.

```
billing LIKE '%"ContractEnd":"0"%'
```

needs to be `billing ="ContractEnd":"0"`

How do I do it?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: thank you for the reply

Comment: You're working with json data and you're doing a raw search on the text version?  Take a look at the json structure (e.g., with `var_dump(App\User)` and walk the object instead.

Comment: like json_decode?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply  Brett Gregso and  Alive to Die, I figure it out.

I did create a variable and pass the pattern on it,

```
$contract_end = "ContractEnd":"0"';
$user = App\User->whereRaw("(billing LIKE '%".$contract_end."%')")->get();
```